# Errors when running OpenAI's GPT-2 Output Detector

Tags: windows, openai-api

I attempted to run OpenAI's GPT-2 Output Detector locally on a web UI, but when I run the program, it returns this:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for RobertaForSequenceClassification:
        Missing key(s) in state_dict: "roberta.embeddings.position_ids".
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "roberta.pooler.dense.weight", "roberta.pooler.dense.bias".
```

I've tried changing uninstalling and reinstalling a newer version of transformers, but it doesn't help. FYI: I'm running Windows 11.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go at the below file that you have downloaded in your directory from repo:

https://github.com/openai/gpt-2-output-dataset/blob/master/detector/server.py

In the ***server.py*** file, change the following line:

```
self.model.load_state_dict(data['model_state_dict'])
```

with:

```
self.model.load_state_dict(data['model_state_dict'], strict=False)
```

For more information:

https://github.com/openai/gpt-2-output-dataset/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **Google colab notebook** for more information of **GPT-2 output detector**:

It is based on UI with the help of **gradio**:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11OZknA7er__NgH-Yje7__LY5v-huYE0P?usp=share_link